# Randomly Distribute Banknotes of different values to fit a total value

Tags: c#, arrays, math

Given an array of banknotes with values=[1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
what is the best method to randomly distribute these to fit a total sum of e.g. 363?
I don't want to use modulus and add find the remainder by adding bigger notes first. I'd like it to be more random, so that it may have a more natural distribution in which banknotes make up the sum.

Currently I am doing this:

```
int temp = totalAmount;
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
   amounts[i] = temp / values[i];
   temp %= values[i];
}
```

This would give me a note distribution of 3x100, 1x50, 1x10, 3x1, 
but I'd rather it was something like 1x100, 3x50, 2x20, 6x10, 13x13, although I can't come up with a good strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly wanted it to be random, you could do something like this:

```
var rnd = new Random();
int currentValue = 0;
var selectedNotes = new List<int>();

int[] notes = {1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100};
int targetValue = 363;

while (currentValue < targetValue)
{
    int v = rnd.Next(0, notes.Length);

    if (currentValue + notes[v] > targetValue)
    {
        continue;
    }

    selectedNotes.Add(notes[v]);
    currentValue += notes[v];
}

foreach (var note in selectedNotes.GroupBy(z => z).Select(z => new {BankNote = z.Key, Quantity = z.Count()})
    .OrderByDescending(z => z.BankNote))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{note.Quantity}x{note.BankNote}");
}
```

Comment: I'm choosing this. It's straightforward and easy to use. Thanks for the help. It generates nicely!

Answer (score 1):

Mainly for the challenge and to see how this goes, I have written a small class to compute all possible combinations, then you can draw from this bucket.
As a bonus, this would allow to draw any number of unique combinations from the list (with deletion).
However, I have built in a limitation for each note type, eg. 20x. Without any limit, this would run very long (or maybe run out of memory).

```
public static void Main()
{
    var C = new Combinations();
    int targetValue = 363;
    int limitPerNote = 20;

    foreach(int v in new[] {1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100})
    {
        int maxCnt = (int)(targetValue / v);
        maxCnt = Math.Min(maxCnt, limitPerNote);
        C.Add(v, maxCnt);
    }

    List<String> Results = new List<String>();
    while(!C.Inc())
    {
        if(C.TotalValue==targetValue)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(C.CurrentCombinationToString());
            Results.Add(C.CurrentCombinationToString());
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{Results.Count} combinations found");

    Random random = new Random();
    Console.WriteLine($"Random combination:");
    Console.WriteLine(Results[random.Next(0, Results.Count)]);
}

public class Combinations
{
    private List<CombinationItem> Items {get; set;} = new List<CombinationItem>();

    public void Add(int value, int maxCount)
    {
        Items.Add(new CombinationItem() {Value=value, MaxCount = maxCount});
    }

    public bool Inc()
    {
        int i = Items.Count -1;
        bool overflowFlag = true;
        while(overflowFlag)
        {
            overflowFlag = Items[i].Inc();
            if(overflowFlag) i--;
            if(i<0) return true; // final overflow, last combination reached
        }
        return false; // return without final overflow
    }

    public int TotalValue
    {get{ return Items.Sum((item) => item.Value * item.Count); }}

    public string CurrentCombinationToString()
    {
        return String.Join(" + ", Items.
        Where((item) => item.Count >0).
        Select((item) => $@"{item.Count}x {item.Value}"));
    }

}

public class CombinationItem
{
    public int Value {get; set;}
    public int Count {get; set;}
    public int MaxCount {get; set;}

    public bool Inc()
    {
        // returns true on overflow
        Count++;
        if(Count > MaxCount)
        {
            Count=0;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Really cool solution. It looks a little overkill, it would be nice to be able to perform this in real time for many instances. I'll see how it works out

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
        Random random = new Random();

        int[] values = { 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100 };
        int[] amounts = new int[values.Length];
        int totalAmount = 363;

        int left = totalAmount;
        while (left > 0)
        {
            int nextNote = random.Next(0, values.Length);
            if (values[nextNote] < left)
            {
                left -= values[nextNote];
                amounts[nextNote]++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `amounts.Zip(values, (a,v) => a * v).Sum() == totalAmount` //false

Comment: Made a tippo, fixed it, a little late, but fixed nonetheless.